# How to ignore @input event on page load from vuex computed getter in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, quasar-framework, debouncing

I'm using vue and debounce to do an auto-save-like experience on my text fields after 3 seconds of no typing activity my users.  The way I trigger the debounce is based on the `@input` event on each of the text fields.  The `v-model` for all of the text fields are populated from a `vuex` computed getter called `currentItem`.

When the page loads, the action that populates `currentItem` is dispatched and `currentItem` receives the data from the action. This triggers an `@input` event and hence, my debounce function fires 3 seconds after the page loads.

How can I prevent the `@input` event from firing on page load in this situation or find a work-around here?

Pretty stumped on what to try, feels like any route I go down I'll run into the same predicament.

```
<div class="col-6 q-pa-sm">
  <q-input
    v-model="currentItem.imageUrl"
    @input="putItem"
    label="Image URL"
    outlined>
  </q-input>
</div>
```

```
putItem() {
  this.savingStatus = "Saving changes...";
  this.debounceItem();
},
```

```
debounceItem: debounce(function() {
   this.$axios
      .put(`/v1/items/${this.currentItem.id}`, this.currentItem)
      .catch(error => {
         this.showSnackbarError(error);
       })
      }
}, 1000),
```

Comment: What is `<q-input>`? What framework? Please tag the question.

Comment: quasar. apologies.

Comment: Why not watch changes to `currentItem.imageUrl`? The watcher will only be fired when it’s value changes.

Comment: The value will still change on page load when the vuex action is dispatched populating currentItem with data

Comment: My understanding is `input` is only fired when the user changes the input value (e.g. by typing into the field). You changing the input value programmatically should not cause the `input` event to fire. I just did a test on jsfiddle and confirmed this, so I don't understand how the `input` event is firing for you. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Interesting. Let me take a closer look and get back in a little